# laravel 4: URL::route vs jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

(As new laravel user) I'm trying to build a ajax call url through the laravel URL::class:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: '{{ URL::route('getUser', ['3']) }}', 
    success: function(results) {
    alert(results);
    }
});
```

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('admin/getUser/{user_id}', array(
   'as' => 'getUser', 
   'uses' => 'AdminController@getUser'
));
```

Instead of the hard coded `3` this parameter should come from jquery (e.g. `$(this).attr('user_id')`).

Can someone tell me how to create the URL dynamically?

It seems that because of the route definition the `URL::route` function needs the parameter hardcoded or as a php varaible.

I hope this is +/- clear...

Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the url clean and pass the variable as data in your ajax call.

```
var urlGetUser = "{{ URL::route('getUser') }}",
    userId = $(this).attr('user_id');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: urlGetUser,
  data: { id: userId }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( msg );
});
```

This way you won't have to create ajax calls for every possible user ID. Something both other current solutions also offer.

Disclaimer: Colleague of asker with absolutely no experience in Laravel :/

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I guess doing $ajax type="POST" is the cleanest solution!

Comment: re: 'This way you won't have to create ajax calls for every possible user ID' -> I was aware of the hardcoded ID ;-) Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using URL::to() for my Ajax calls. I've had problems to. But if you do use URL::to() you would be able to use javascript variables.
try this:

```
$id = 3;
"{{URL::to('getUser/'".$id.")}}"
```

Hope this helps, I'm new too. if you find a better way to do this awesome, let me know ;)

Comment: 1. you missed bracket
2. it is not working:
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"+id+"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: @MarekBernád You are correct. I mixed Javascript syntax with php. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP actually handles the file before passing it to the browser it may be indeed impossible to dynamically use a php variable directly, but theres a way around it. This may work ONLY if you havent type-casted your route parameter `user_id` to a certain definition.

```
// Add a placeholder which we'll use jQuery to swap out later
urlTo = "{{ URL::route('getUser', ['%userid%']) }}";

// swap out the placeholder dynamically using jQuery
urlTo = urlTo.replace('%userid%', $('#someElement').attr('user_id'));

$.ajax({
    url: urlTo, 
    success: function(results) {
        alert(results);
    }
});
```

What we've done here is to create a placeholder in our URL generated from a route so we'll probably have a URL like `http://localhost/app/profile/%userid%` after PHP has finished processing. We then use jQuery to replace the placeholder to our actual dynamic value.