# Want to send data to another view using link

Tags: javascript, laravel-4

Here is my code. Here I want to send an id into the link. But it don't work.

```
<script>
$("#cat3").on('click',function (e) {
//console.log(e);

var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat').value;
var sub_id=document.getElementById('sub').value;
$.get('/ajax3?cat1_id=' +cat_id + '&sub_id=' + sub_id  ,function(data)
    {

$('#sub1').empty();
$.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
{
$('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.shift+'</li>'+'{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click",array($subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo))}}');
})

});
});

i=0;

</script>
```

the code works when i use:

```
$('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.shift+'</li>'+'{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click")}}');
```

but don't work when i tried to send the id into the link. like this:

```
$('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.shift+'</li>'+'{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click",array($subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo))}}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to put the third parameter on a array

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine", "click", $subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo) }}
```

EDIT :

I was tired so I didn't pay attention on the main problem.
You mixed some PHP and a asynchronous function.
So your route will always be the same at the page on runtime

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine", "click") }} // <a href="/routine">click</a>
```

So if let's said that `$subcarObj->idstudent = 4`

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click",array($subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo))}} // <a href="/routine/4">click</a>
```

So when you did this :

```
$.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
$('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.shift+'</li>'+'{{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click",array($subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo))}}');
```

So for every loop you will get the same

```
URL {{ HTML::linkRoute("routine","click",array($subcatObj->idstudent_academicinfo))}} // <a href="/routine/4">click</a>
```

There's some tricky solutions to come over this problem. Please take a look at this post

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143067/4606106

I hope you understand your problem better. Just tell me on comment if you have any questions :)

Comment: Ok I was tired I didn't really pay attention. but i didn't paid attention on the javascript