# Laravel 5.4 : how to pass variable to route with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, routes

I want to pass a variable 'id' to my route with JavaScript. Following is my JavaScript code:

```
    <script>
function edit_city(id){

$.post("edit_city/"+id, function(page_response)
{
alert(page_response);
});
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('edit_city/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo $id;
});
```

Please Help. i don't know where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change your $.post call to

```
$.post("edit_city/"+id, function(page_response)
{
    alert(page_response);
});
```

Putting  {id: id} in the second parameter sends it as Post data, but your route is expecting the ID as part of the URL

Comment: Noticed a typo. Try removing the '/' before edit_city

Comment: it still does not work :( I updated my question as well

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088313/laravel-4-urlroute-vs-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

> you need to give full path with host name. does this help.

```
  <script>
    function edit_city(id){
    var url= '{{url("edit_city")}}' + ' /' +id;
    $.post(url, function(page_response)
    {
       alert(page_response);
    });
    }
    </script>
```